# How to use FindGDAL on Windows?

Tags: windows, cmake, gdal

Our program needs gdal, so we got it, and compiled it using their directions. As such, C:\warmerda\bld\include has .h files, C:\warmerda\bld\lib has gdal.lib and gdal_i.lib, and so on.

I have this in my CMakeLists.txt:

```
set(GDAL_DIR C:/warmerda/bld)
find_package(GDAL REQUIRED)
```

However, when I run cmake, all I get is this:

```
$ cmake . -G"Visual Studio 14 2015 Win64"
-- Boost version: 1.59.0
CMake Error at C:/Program Files (x86)/CMake/share/cmake-3.5/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:148 (message):
  Could NOT find GDAL (missing: GDAL_LIBRARY GDAL_INCLUDE_DIR)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Program Files (x86)/CMake/share/cmake-3.5/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:388 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  C:/Program Files (x86)/CMake/share/cmake-3.5/Modules/FindGDAL.cmake:116 (FIND_PACKAGE_HANDLE_STANDARD_ARGS)
  main/CMakeLists.txt:31 (find_package)
```

Comment: As always: Add the GDAL path to the `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH`, this is not specific to Windows or GDAL.

Comment: Why not make this an official answer? (It worked for me, thanks)

Comment: Because it is a quite unspecific advice. I wrote a more general question and answer, see http://stackoverflow.com/q/39126648/2799037