# CMake does not find includes / libraries

Tags: cmake

I want to use some third-party headers (or a library) in a project that uses CMake. But it does not find the headers (the library). Why does CMake not find it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CMake's find routines look for headers and libraries at some specific places. This includes the `PATH` variable, and the default locations for installed software, e.g., for many Linuces `/usr/bin`. Additionally, it evaluates the CMake variable `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH`.

You have two possibilities to help CMake finding the required files:

1. Check whether your software is properly installed. For self-compiled software, that's usually done by `make install` or similar. If you use packages (RPM or deb), they are in general installed and can be found with the `PATH` variable.
2. If you don't want or can install the software, add its path to the `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` variable. Either pass it to the CMake call `cmake -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/path/to/software ..` or edit/add the according field in the CMake-GUI.

You have to delete the `CMakeCache.txt`, otherwise CMake will not find the library, because it does not check but use the cached result. Re-run CMake and it should work.

### Evaluation order

If you have multiple versions of a library on your system, add the one you want to use to the `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` as the variables gets evaluated prior to the system path variables.

### Module-specific variables

Some modules offer specific variables like `mylib_DIR` or `mylib_ROOT` to indicate the search path. Its use is discouraged and they are only left for backwards-compatibility. New modules don't have these modules and commits adding such variables are rejected by the CMake developers.

### Documentation

More details on how CMake searches files and in which order can be found in the documentation: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_library.html