# find SFML with CMake on Windows

Tags: cmake, sfml

I compiled SFML on windows (MinGW) and find myself with a directory structure with bin, include, lib and a cmake/Modules/FindSFML.cmake file.

I can't find how to use SFML in the CMakeLists.txt, whether it is

```
find_package(SFML REQUIRED)
```

or

```
find_package(SFML CONFIG REQUIRED)
```

All I get when I use cmake is:

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:34 (find_package):
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "SFML" with any of
  the following names:

    SFMLConfig.cmake
    sfml-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "SFML" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "SFML_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "SFML"
  provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been
  installed.
```

I tried setting manually:

```
SFML_DIR:PATH=E:/code/libraries/SFML-2.4.0
CMAKE_MODULE_PATH:PATH=E:/code/libraries/SFML-2.4.0
```

or

```
CMAKE_MODULE_PATH:PATH=E:/code/libraries/SFML-2.4.0/cmake/modules
```

But I'm not making any progress.

Comment: Does this answer help? http://stackoverflow.com/a/39126731/2799037

Comment: Please add your cmake calls. Why do you add `cmake/modules`? Why the CMAKE_MODULE_PATH and not the CMAKE_PREFIX path?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the step by step guide we were provided (picture). When this is done you have to remember that you need to link the librarys to your program, with this line:
    `target_link_libraries (<Name of project here> sfml-graphics sfml-window sfml-system)`
if you want to use audi library in SFML just add `sfml-audio` at the end and so on.
in debug mode you should have a `-d`at the end of each library. Like this `sfml-graphics-d`.
If you do some big change in CMake or changing project you need to add:
`-IC:/dev/libs/SFML/include -LC:/dev/libs/SFML/lib`back again.
(You can add the folder where you want). `-I`is for Include folders and `-L`is for all lib folders, you need this letter in front of all paths.
If you have problems linking /bin folder up you can drop all the `.dll` files inside System32 folder(for 64-bit, SysWOW64 for 32-bit).
And remember, have a GW that is matching SFML.

[image: Step by step guide]

[image: information]

[image: What to include]

[image: flags]

Answer (score 0):

When I got same error in cmake-gui, all I did - added entry with name "SFMLDIR" and value with path to sfml directory.