# find_package does not find GTest which is part of CMake

Tags: c++, cmake, googletest

I want to find `GTest` via:

```
find_package(GTest REQUIRED)
```

But it is not found:

> Error:Could NOT find GTest (missing: GTEST_LIBRARY GTEST_INCLUDE_DIR GTEST_MAIN_LIBRARY)

I know from this [link](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindGTest.html) that `GTest` should be distributed via standard CMake.

Can you tell me what I did wrong?

Comment: Why do you think GTest is part of CMake? Have you seen `GTEST_ADD_TESTS`, maybe you just want to use that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CMake does not find includes / libraries](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39126648/cmake-does-not-find-includes-libraries)

Answer (score 3):

`find_package` does not look in CMake's installation directory. It only evaluates the `PATH` and `CMAKE_PREFIX_VARIABLES`. Just add the path to CMake's GTest to the latter variable, clear your CMake cache and re-run CMake.

Comment: I found FindGTest.cmake at 
/Applications/Clion.app/Contents/bin/cmake/share/cmake-3.6/Modules/

Answer (score 3):

If you're on Ubuntu, you should read `/usr/share/doc/libgtest-dev/README.Debian`. It says:

> The Google C++ Testing Framework uses conditional compilation for some
>   things.  Because of the C++ "One Definition Rule", gtest must be
>   compiled with exactly the same flags as your C++ code under test.
>   Because this is hard to manage, upstream no longer recommends using
>   precompiled libraries

So you should compile and install your own version of the `gtest` library with the exactly same Compiler Options, and set the `GTEST_LIBRARY` or `GTEST_ROOT` variable accordingly.

For example, I did the following:

```
$ mkdir -p ExternalLibs/gTest
$ cd ExternalLibs/gTest
$ cmake /usr/src/gtest
$ make
```

Then I added the following lines in my `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
set (GTEST_ROOT ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/ExternalLibs/gTest)
find_package(GTest REQUIRED)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have gtest installed you can just do:

```
add_subdirectory("/usr/src/gtest" ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/gtest)
enable_testing()
include_directories(${GTEST_INCLUDE_DIRS})
add_executable(test test.cpp)
target_link_libraries(test gtest gtest_main)
add_test(AllTests test)
```