# How can I include GoogleTest in a test module?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake, visual-studio-2022, googletest

- [GitHub Repo](https://github.com/mns-csharp/MatrixMultiplicationProjectCpp)

The following is the directory structure of the project:

```
MatrixMultiplicationProjectCpp
            ├───CMakeLists.txt
            ├───main.cpp
            │
            ├───lib(googletest)
            │     └───... ... ...
            │
            ├───src
            │     ├───Matrix.hpp
            │     └───Vector.hpp
            │
            └───tst
                  ├───CMakeLists.txt
                  └───test_vector.cpp
```

**root\CMakeLists.txt**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.17)

project(
MatrixMultiplicationProjectCpp
VERSION 1.0
DESCRIPTION "A simple C++ project to demonstrate basic CMake usage" 
LANGUAGES CXX
)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

include_directories(src) # hpp files
add_subdirectory(tst) # test module; this is a binary

# Add main executable
add_executable(MatrixMultiplicationProjectCppExe main.cpp)
```

**tst/CMakeLists.txt**

```
include_directories(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src
        ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/googletest/include
        ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/googlemock/include)

# Add Google Test as a subdirectory
add_subdirectory("${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../lib" "googletest")

# Add the test executable
add_executable(test_vector test_vector.cpp )

# Add the test to CTest
add_test(NAME test_vector COMMAND test_vector)
```

I am getting the following error:

```
====================[ Build | all | Debug ]=====================================
"C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\JetBrains\CLion 2022.1.3\bin\cmake\win\bin\cmake.exe" --build C:\git\CUDA__lab\MatrixMultiplicationProjectCpp\cmake-build-debug --target all -j 3
[1/15] Building CXX object CMakeFiles\MatrixMultiplicationProjectCppExe.dir\main.cpp.obj
[2/15] Building CXX object tst\CMakeFiles\test_vector.dir\test_vector.cpp.obj
[3/15] Linking CXX executable MatrixMultiplicationProjectCppExe.exe
[4/15] Linking CXX executable tst\test_vector.exe
FAILED: tst/test_vector.exe 
cmd.exe /C "cd . && "C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\JetBrains\CLion 2022.1.3\bin\cmake\win\bin\cmake.exe" -E vs_link_exe --intdir=tst\CMakeFiles\test_vector.dir --rc=C:\PROGRA~2\WI3CF2~1\10\bin\10.0.22000.0\x86\rc.exe --mt=C:\PROGRA~2\WI3CF2~1\10\bin\10.0.22000.0\x86\mt.exe --manifests  -- "C:\PROGRA~2\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.20.27508\bin\Hostx86\x86\link.exe" /nologo tst\CMakeFiles\test_vector.dir\test_vector.cpp.obj  /out:tst\test_vector.exe /implib:tst\test_vector.lib /pdb:tst\test_vector.pdb /version:0.0 /machine:X86 /debug /INCREMENTAL /subsystem:console  kernel32.lib user32.lib gdi32.lib winspool.lib shell32.lib ole32.lib oleaut32.lib uuid.lib comdlg32.lib advapi32.lib && cd ."
LINK Pass 1: command "C:\PROGRA~2\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.20.27508\bin\Hostx86\x86\link.exe /nologo tst\CMakeFiles\test_vector.dir\test_vector.cpp.obj /out:tst\test_vector.exe /implib:tst\test_vector.lib /pdb:tst\test_vector.pdb /version:0.0 /machine:X86 /debug /INCREMENTAL /subsystem:console kernel32.lib user32.lib gdi32.lib winspool.lib shell32.lib ole32.lib oleaut32.lib uuid.lib comdlg32.lib advapi32.lib /MANIFEST /MANIFESTFILE:tst\CMakeFiles\test_vector.dir/intermediate.manifest tst\CMakeFiles\test_vector.dir/manifest.res" failed (exit code 1120) with the following output:
test_vector.cpp.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "bool __cdecl testing::internal::IsTrue(bool)" (?IsTrue@internal@testing@@YA_N_N@Z) referenced in function "public: static void (__cdecl*__cdecl testing::internal::SuiteApiResolver<class testing::Test>::GetSetUpCaseOrSuite(char const *,int))(void)" (?GetSetUpCaseOrSuite@?$SuiteApiResolver@VTest@testing@@@internal@testing@@SAP6AXXZPBDH@Z)
test_vector.cpp.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall testing::internal::GTestLog::GTestLog(enum testing::internal::GTestLogSeverity,char const *,int)" (??0GTestLog@internal@testing@@QAE@W4GTestLogSeverity@12@PBDH@Z) referenced in function "public: static void (__cdecl*__cdecl testing::internal::SuiteApiResolver<class testing::Test>::GetSetUpCaseOrSuite(char const *,int))(void)" (?GetSetUpCaseOrSuite@?$SuiteApiResolver@VTest@testing@@@internal@testing@@SAP6AXXZPBDH@Z)
test_vector.cpp.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall testing::internal::GTestLog::~GTestLog(void)" (??1GTestLog@internal@testing@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function "public: static void (__cdecl*__cdecl testing::internal::SuiteApiResolver<class testing::Test>::GetSetUpCaseOrSuite(char const *,int))(void)" (?GetSetUpCaseOrSuite@?$SuiteApiResolver@VTest@testing@@@internal@testing@@SAP6AXXZPBDH@Z)
test_vector.cpp.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall testing::Message::Message(void)" (??0Message@testing@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function "private: virtual void __thiscall VectorTest_Constructor_Test::TestBody(void)" (?TestBody@VectorTest_Constructor_Test@@EAEXXZ)
test_vector.cpp.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "class testing::AssertionResult __cdecl testing::AssertionSuccess(void)" (?AssertionSuccess@testing@@YA?AVAssertionResult@1@XZ) referenced in function "class testing::AssertionResult __cdecl testing::internal::CmpHelperEQ<int,int>(char const *,char const *,int const &,int const &)" (??$CmpHelperEQ@HH@internal@testing@@YA?AVAssertionResult@1@PBD0ABH1@Z)
test_vector.cpp.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > __cdecl testing::internal::StringStreamToString(class std::basic_stringstream<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > *)" (?StringStreamToString@internal@testing@@YA?AV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@PAV?$basic_stringstream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@4@@Z) referenced in function "class testing::AssertionResult __cdecl testing::internal::CmpHelperFloatingPointEQ<double>(char const *,char const *,double,double)" (??$CmpHelperFloatingPointEQ@N@internal@testing@@YA?AVAssertionResult@1@PBD0NN@Z)
test_vector.cpp.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "class testing::AssertionResult __cdecl testing::internal::EqFailure(char const *,char const *,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &,bool)" (?EqFailure@internal@testing@@YA?AVAssertionResult@2@PBD0ABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@1_N@Z) referenced in function "class testing::AssertionResult __cdecl testing::internal::CmpHelperEQFailure<int,int>(char const *,char const *,int const &,int const &)" (??$CmpHelperEQFailure@HH@internal@testing@@YA?AVAssertionResult@1@PBD0ABH1@Z)
test_vector.cpp.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void const * __cdecl testing::internal::GetTestTypeId(void)" (?GetTestTypeId@internal@testing@@YAPBXXZ) referenced in function "void __cdecl `dynamic initializer for 'private: static class testing::TestInfo * VectorTest_AccessorMethods_Test::test_info_''(void)" (??__E?test_info_@VectorTest_AccessorMethods_Test@@0QAVTestInfo@testing@@A@@YAXXZ)
test_vector.cpp.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "class testing::TestInfo * __cdecl testing::internal::MakeAndRegisterTestInfo(char const *,char const *,char const *,char const *,struct testing::internal::CodeLocation,void const *,void (__cdecl*)(void),void (__cdecl*)(void),class testing::internal::TestFactoryBase *)" (?MakeAndRegisterTestInfo@internal@testing@@YAPAVTestInfo@2@PBD000UCodeLocation@12@PBXP6AXXZ3PAVTestFactoryBase@12@@Z) referenced in function "void __cdecl `dynamic initializer for 'private: static class testing::TestInfo * VectorTest_AccessorMethods_Test::test_info_''(void)" (??__E?test_info_@VectorTest_AccessorMethods_Test@@0QAVTestInfo@testing@@A@@YAXXZ)
test_vector.cpp.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "bool __cdecl testing::internal::AlwaysTrue(void)" (?AlwaysTrue@internal@testing@@YA_NXZ) referenced in function "private: virtual void __thiscall VectorTest_DotProductInvalidDimensions_Test::TestBody(void)" (?TestBody@VectorTest_DotProductInvalidDimensions_Test@@EAEXXZ)
test_vector.cpp.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual __thiscall testing::Test::~Test(void)" (??1Test@testing@@UAE@XZ) referenced in function "public: virtual __thiscall VectorTest_AccessorMethods_Test::~VectorTest_AccessorMethods_Test(void)" (??1VectorTest_AccessorMethods_Test@@UAE@XZ)
test_vector.cpp.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "protected: __thiscall testing::Test::Test(void)" (??0Test@testing@@IAE@XZ) referenced in function "public: __thiscall VectorTest_AccessorMethods_Test::VectorTest_AccessorMethods_Test(void)" (??0VectorTest_AccessorMethods_Test@@QAE@XZ)
test_vector.cpp.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "protected: virtual void __thiscall testing::Test::SetUp(void)" (?SetUp@Test@testing@@MAEXXZ)
test_vector.cpp.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "protected: virtual void __thiscall testing::Test::TearDown(void)" (?TearDown@Test@testing@@MAEXXZ)
test_vector.cpp.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: static class testing::UnitTest * __cdecl testing::UnitTest::GetInstance(void)" (?GetInstance@UnitTest@testing@@SAPAV12@XZ) referenced in function "int __cdecl RUN_ALL_TESTS(void)" (?RUN_ALL_TESTS@@YAHXZ)
test_vector.cpp.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: int __thiscall testing::UnitTest::Run(void)" (?Run@UnitTest@testing@@QAEHXZ) referenced in function "int __cdecl RUN_ALL_TESTS(void)" (?RUN_ALL_TESTS@@YAHXZ)
test_vector.cpp.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl testing::InitGoogleTest(int *,char * *)" (?InitGoogleTest@testing@@YAXPAHPAPAD@Z) referenced in function __catch$?TestBody@VectorTest_DotProductInvalidDimensions_Test@@EAEXXZ$3
test_vector.cpp.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall testing::internal::AssertHelper::AssertHelper(enum testing::TestPartResult::Type,char const *,int,char const *)" (??0AssertHelper@internal@testing@@QAE@W4Type@TestPartResult@2@PBDH1@Z) referenced in function "private: virtual void __thiscall VectorTest_Constructor_Test::TestBody(void)" (?TestBody@VectorTest_Constructor_Test@@EAEXXZ)
test_vector.cpp.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall testing::internal::AssertHelper::~AssertHelper(void)" (??1AssertHelper@internal@testing@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function "private: virtual void __thiscall VectorTest_Constructor_Test::TestBody(void)" (?TestBody@VectorTest_Constructor_Test@@EAEXXZ)
test_vector.cpp.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall testing::internal::AssertHelper::operator=(class testing::Message const &)const " (??4AssertHelper@internal@testing@@QBEXABVMessage@2@@Z) referenced in function "private: virtual void __thiscall VectorTest_Constructor_Test::TestBody(void)" (?TestBody@VectorTest_Constructor_Test@@EAEXXZ)
tst\test_vector.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 20 unresolved externals
[5/15] Building CXX object tst\googletest\googlemock\CMakeFiles\gmock.dir\src\gmock-all.cc.obj
[6/15] Building CXX object tst\googletest\googlemock\CMakeFiles\gmock.dir\__\googletest\src\gtest-all.cc.obj
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

The test module is not finding the `googletest` framework.

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Use `find_package` instead. https://stackoverflow.com/a/44649433/4123703

Comment: If your googletest is source code, then follow [cmake-quickstart](http://google.github.io/googletest/quickstart-cmake.html) might be easier.