# GTest build first at CMake

Tags: c++, cmake, googletest

I'm building dynamic library and want to use gtest for testing.

```
SET(GTEST_LIBRARY libs/googletest-master)
set(GTEST_INCLUDE_DIR libs/googletest-master/googletest/include)
#set(GTEST_MAIN_LIBRARY libs/googletest-master/googletest/include/gtest)

#find_package(PostgreSQL REQUIRED)

enable_testing()
find_package(GTest REQUIRED)
include_directories(${GTEST_INCLUDE_DIR})
```

But, berofe setting GTEST_MAIN_LIBRARY I have to build it first.
How I can configure CMake to achieve this

1. Build gtest with Cmake && make (on unix)
2. Get appropriate path to GTEST_MAIN_LIBRARY
3. continue build

Comment: It's difficult to understand you question (the format, some bold, line breaks...), could you improve?

Comment: Please reformat your question to be more straightforward as to what is going on.

Comment: Maybe helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39126731/2799037

Answer (score 0):

I copied gtests srcs into project 
make a build with Make
and add this to CMake

```html
add_subdirectory(libs/googletest-master)

SET(GTEST_LIBRARY libs/googletest-master)
set(GTEST_INCLUDE_DIR libs/googletest-master/googletest/include)
set(GTEST_MAIN_LIBRARY libs/googletest-master/googlemock/gtest)

enable_testing()
find_package(GTest REQUIRED)
include_directories(${GTEST_INCLUDE_DIR})
include_directories(${gtest_SOURCE_DIR}/include ${gtest_SOURCE_DIR})
```

Answer (score -2):

If your put the source for googletest in a subdirectory parented where your CMakeLists.txt file is, the following should work:

```
add_subdirectory(./googletest)

add_executable(your_program ${MY_SRC})

add_dependencies(your_program gmock)
add_dependencies(your_program gtest)
```