# Cmake error: by not providing "FindOpenCV.cmake" in CMAKE_MOUDLE_PATH

Tags: c++, windows, opencv, cmake

When I try to use `cmake ..`, the Windows cmd points out an error:

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:15(find_package):
  By not providing "FindOpenCV.cmake" in CMAKE_MOUDLE_PATH this project has 
  asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "OpenCV", but
  CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "OpenCV" with any of 
  the following names:

    OpenCVConfig.cmake
    opencv-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "OpenCV" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set 
  "OpenCV_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files. If "OpenCV" 
  provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been installed.
```

And I have searched many possible solutions online but it doesnt work...
For example:

- write in command line `cmake -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH="C:\OpenCV" ..`
  but it seems cmd doesnt know DCMAKE at all...
- or `cmake -DOpenCV_DIR="C:\OpenCV\build\x86\vc10\lib" ..` also doesnt work.

I am not sure if those solutions are in Linux or Windows, because my computer is windows7 system... I think the error has explained how to fix it, which is

> Add the installation prefix of "OpenCV" to CAMKE_PREFIX_PATH or set "OpenCV_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.

but I don't know exactly how to write the command code...
Please give me some hint...

Comment: So, what root directory for your *OpenCV installation* is? Root directory is a common prefix for libraries (`.dll`) and header files (`.h`) which comes with the package. Check that file `OpenCVConfig.cmake` exists under that prefix. Also, what do you mean by `but it seems cmd doesnt know DCMAKE at all`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CMake does not find includes / libraries](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39126648/cmake-does-not-find-includes-libraries)

Answer (score -1):

A quick solution might be to edit the `CMakeLists.txt` to include the path for the `OpenCV_DIR` variable by adding the following line **before** the `find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)`:

```
set("OpenCV_DIR" "C:\OpenCV\build\x86\vc10\lib")
```

Folder containing the `OpenCVConfig.cmake` can also be found by:

```
find / -name "OpenCVConfig.cmake"
```