# How to set gperftools path variables GPERFTOOLS_LIBRARIES GPERFTOOLS_INCLUDE_DIR?

Tags: cmake, catkin

In a catkin project the catkin_make fails. The  CMakeLists includes

```
find_package(Gperftools REQUIRED)
```

I have installed google-perftools:

```
google-perftools is already the newest version (2.4-0ubuntu5)
```

The CMake Error says it cannot find gperftools, or at least the path variables:

```
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.5/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:148 (message):
  Could NOT find Gperftools (missing: GPERFTOOLS_LIBRARIES
  GPERFTOOLS_INCLUDE_DIR)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake-3.5/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:388 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  tuw_mpn/FindGperftools.cmake:39 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
  tuw_mpn/CMakeLists.txt:40 (find_package)
```

After a few hours of searching I haven't found a description of the setup. Could someone please explain how I can solve this error?

Thanks in advance and I hope I have provided enough information for this problem.

Cheers,
Michael

Comment: General advice on how to teach CMake to find libraries: http://stackoverflow.com/q/39126648/2799037 If this does not help, you have to ask more specific. Have you ever deleted your CMake cache / build directory and tried again?

Answer (score 3):

I use Ubuntu 16.04 and have the same problems with you. I think the problem is lack some packages:

```
sudo apt-get install gperf  libgoogle-perftools-dev
```

have solved my problems,you can have a try.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure which script `FindGperftools.cmake` you use, but [this one](https://github.com/vast-io/vast/blob/master/cmake/FindGperftools.cmake) searches for library `tcmalloc_and_profiler` and header `gperftools/heap-profiler.h`.

But package `google-perftools` [doesn't provide](http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/all/google-perftools/filelist) these files. (Actually, this package doesn't provide any headers or library.)

The library is [provided](http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/amd64/libgoogle-perftools4/filelist) by `libgoogle-perftools4` package. Probably, there are should be some devel package which provides the header.

Answer (score 2):

You need to provide `FindGperftools.cmake`

For example from:
https://github.com/vast-io/vast/blob/master/cmake/FindGperftools.cmake

In the `CMakeLists.txt` add the following:

```
# set the path to the library folder
link_directories(/usr/local/lib)

#Append Gperftools_DIR 
LIST(APPEND CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "/DirectoryWhereTheFindGperftools.cmakeIs")

find_package(Gperftools REQUIRED)
```