# cmake: how to use custom executable path for bison

Tags: cmake

I would like to point cmake to a specific location to find the Bison executable on a specific platform.  Is there a way to do this?

```
if(PLATFORM STREQUAL "Darwin")
  find_package(
    BISON 3.0.0 REQUIRED
    # Would like to do something like:
    PATH "/usr/local/opt/bison/bin/bison"
    )
else()
  find_package(
    BISON 3.0.0 REQUIRED
    )
endif()
if(BISON_FOUND)
  BISON_TARGET(
    Parser
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/Parser.yy
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/Parser.cpp
    )
  target_sources(
    MyLib PRIVATE
    ${BISON_Parser_OUTPUTS}
    )
endif()
```

Comment: Use CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH, see http://stackoverflow.com/q/39126648/2799037

Comment: Thanks!  I thought I had tried that but apparently had not.

Answer (score 3):

According to [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/module/FindBISON.html) for module `FindBISON.cmake`, this module sets variable *BISON_EXECUTABLE* pointed to the program's executable.

Actually, this is **cached variable**, which is set be the script with [find_program](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/command/find_program.html) call. So you may set this cached variable manually for fix executable:

```
if(PLATFORM STREQUAL "Darwin")
    set(BISON_EXECUTABLE "/usr/local/opt/bison/bin/bison" CACHE PATH "Bison executable")
endif()
...
find_package(BISON 3.0.0 REQUIRED)
```

---

Note, that variables listed in documentation for different scripts `FindXXX.cmake` under

> module defines the following variables:

*don't need to be cached*, so setting them will affect on result. E.g., variable *BISON_VERSION* listed in the same documentation for `FindBISON.cmake` is *not cached*, so you may not redefine it for affect on the script.