# Cmake with Flex/Bison on windows

Tags: c++, cmake, bison, flex-lexer

I downdloaded [this](https://sourceforge.net/projects/winflexbison/) flex/bison executables. I copied them to `C:\Program Files\Flex-Bison`. I also added this dir to Path
When using this buildscript, how can I make CMake find the executables in this folder?

```
CMAKE_MINIMUM_REQUIRED(VERSION 3.8.2)

find_package(FLEX)
if(NOT FLEX_FOUND)
    message(SEND_ERROR "Flex not found")
endif()

find_package(BISON)
if(NOT BISON_FOUND)
    message(SEND_ERROR "Bison not found")
endif()
```

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40859379/3048763) answer for a similar question.

Comment: The comment that was deleted could eventually help me but I have no idea how those variables are called. Somewhat with package dir

Answer (score 0):

I checked [FindFlex](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/master/Modules/FindFLEX.cmake) and [FindBISON](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/master/Modules/FindBISON.cmake) CMake modules and they don't seem to use the usual `<package>_DIR` and `<package>_ROOT` hints (the latter would also have been useful for [`find_program`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_program.html), which has a mode to utilize that).

So, the easiest solution would be to place both executables in your `PATH` variable, which will allow their invocation from anywhere. Otherwise, you may also amend that `PATH` with a custom location of your choice.