# CMake GUI - set folder in windows ( VTK is not found)

Tags: windows, opencv, cmake, vtk

I'm trying to compile OpenCV on Windows 10 with all the modules (following [this tutorial](http://building-and-installing-opencv-3-0-on-windows-7-64-bit/)).

This is the error I get after pressing "Configure":

```
VTK is not found. Please set -DVTK_DIR in CMake to VTK build directory,
or to VTK install subdirectory with VTKConfig.cmake file
```

I've installed VTK 7 by the `msi` file.

I tried to specify a library path but it didn't help (using the same method from [here](http://cmake-gui-specify-library-path-for-windows)), and also set an environment path for this.

What else can I do to pass this error?

Comment: Probably a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/39126648/2799037 Have you deleted your CMake cache file?

Comment: sure, did nothing.

Comment: Have you tried with VTK 6? The 7 is maybe too new?

Comment: I tried, after the first configuration, I'm changing the `VTK_DIR` from `VTK_DIR-NOTFOUND` to the bin folder, But after pressing `Configure` again - the error message is the sane, and the `VTK_DIR` value change back to not-found. What is it ??

Comment: I observe the same nonsence even now in 2017 :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46268235/cmake-gui-resets-parameter-how-do-i-set-parameter-in-cmake-gui?noredirect=1#comment79499006_46268235

Comment: I've had to do `-DVTK_DIR="F:\Programme\Libs\VTK-9.1.0\clion-mingw-build-release` where the path is the folder that contains the `bin` folder, and more importantly that contains a `vtk-config.cmake`