# Cmake gui resets parameter. How do I set parameter in cmake gui?

Tags: opencv, cmake, vtk, cmake-gui

I am trying to build cmake after vtk has been built. I see that WITH_VTK is checked, so I try to change VTK_PATH inplace:

[image]

Unfortunately I get this message

**VTK is not found. Please set -DVTK_DIR in CMake to VTK build directory, or to VTK**

in log window and also the variable resets after pressing **Configure** or **Generate**. I tried to clear cache from File menu. And also tried to '**Add Entry**'. Nothing helps. Is there any instruction how to set parameter in this beautifull app?

Comment: Try the VTK parent folder, without the bin/Debug subfolders.

Comment: @Zindarod, this doesn't help, the parameter is erased by gui.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I've found out how to conquer it:

1. clear cache
2. Add Entry VTK_DIR pointing not to the bin/Debug folder, but to the C:\VTK-8.0.1-bin itself
3. Now press Configure and Generate then.

Comment: I did that and GUI still removed it.

Comment: removed what? clarify please