# FIndlibftd2xx.cmake failing under windows

Tags: module, cmake

Im trying to build a cmake based library under windows10.  I've installed ftd2xx.lib and its supporting packages using its auto-installer.  I'm getting the error that Findlibftd2xx.cmake can't find the library.

Where in windows do the various parts of the library need to be so this module can find it?

Thanks

Comment: I don't know about this library but in a lot of cases you need to tell cmake-gui where the library is since on windows there is no standard location of libraries or include files. Many times setting a _DIR variable will do the trick. You may have to read the `Findlibftd2xx.cmake` to see how and what it is looking for.

Comment: THis question might help http://stackoverflow.com/q/39126648/2799037

Comment: That solved my problem, thank you!