# Wrong Python 2 libraries in CMake

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, opencv, cmake

I am using CMake to build and install OpenCV on my computer running MacOS with python. When I try to specify the python 2 libraries path in CMake, the output always seems to use the wrong file. In my specifications,

`PYTHON2_LIBRARY=/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.13/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/config/libpython2.7.dylib`

However when I run the configure option in CMake the output is:

`Libraries: /usr/lib/libpython2.7.dylib (ver 2.7.10)`

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P2wPq.png) is a picture

Comment: How do you pass the flags? Have you cleared the CMake cache? MIght be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/q/39126648/2799037

Answer (score -1):

It is not clear from your question how you want to import the python libraries. The best way to do it is to call

```
find_package(PythonLibs)
```

If you want to specify which specific installation to use, you can specify the CMake variables `PYTHON_LIBRARY` and `PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIR` beforehand (see [here](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/module/FindPythonLibs.html) for details).