# Build OSVR Tracker viewer Faild, CMake Error : Could NOT find OpenSceneGraph

Tags: cmake, openscenegraph, osvr

I compiled the source code of osvr_tracker_viewer with cmake. I set entries like follow:

> -DBOOST_ROOT="C:/local/boost_1_62_0" ^
>   -DBOOST_LIBRARYDIR="C:/local/boost_1_62_0/lib64-msvc-12.0" ^
>   -Dosvr_DIR="d:/Project/OSVR-Build/OSVR/OSVR-Core/build" ^

and show error like follow:

```
CMake Error at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.7/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:138 (message):
Could NOT find OpenSceneGraph (missing: OPENSCENEGRAPH_LIBRARIES
OPENTHREADS_FOUND OSGDB_FOUND OSGVIEWER_FOUND OSGGA_FOUND OSGUTIL_FOUND
OSG_FOUND)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.7/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:378 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.7/Modules/FindOpenSceneGraph.cmake:223 (FIND_PACKAGE_HANDLE_STANDARD_ARGS)
CMakeLists.txt:11 (find_package)
```

Comment: `Could NOT find OpenSceneGraph` means that it couldn't find OpenSceneGraph library. Check that you have this library installed.

Comment: I have downloaded and built OpenSceneGraph and it ran well. But I don't know how to set entries of OpenSceneGraph library. The message showed "missing OPENSCENEGRAPH_LIBRARIES
OPENTHREADS_FOUND OSGDB_FOUND OSGVIEWER_FOUND OSGGA_FOUND OSGUTIL_FOUND
OSG_FOUN"

Comment: Might be helpful / duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/39126648/2799037

Comment: `But I don't know how to set entries of OpenSceneGraph library.` - There is [on-line description](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/module/FindOpenSceneGraph.html) for `FindOpenSceneGraph` CMake module, the same description is contained at the beginning of file `C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.7/Modules/FindOpenSceneGraph.cmake` on your machine. Also, there are some *universal* approaches for hint about 3d-party library's location, like usr1234567 refers to. If these approaches do not work for your, or you don't understand them - edit your question accordingly.