# How CMake find a different version lib?

Tags: opencv, cmake

I have installed **Opencv 3.2** in system dir (`/usr/local`)... 
CMAKE could find **opencv3.2** automatically well.
But I have to use **opencv 2.4** in my project,so I install **opencv 2.4** in my `~/otherlibs` folder.

Cmakefile:

```
set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH} "~/otherlibs")
find_package(OpenCV 2.4 REQUIRED)
```

but CMAKE always have a error like this:

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:15(find_package):
    Could not find a configuration file for package "OpenCV" that is compatible
    with requested version "2.4"

    The following configuration files were considered but not accepted:
    /usr/local/share/OpenCV/OpenCVConfig.cmake, verison 3.2.0
```

it seems cmake always find system dir and after find Opencv.cmake it will stop to find my specified dir `~/otherlibs`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CMake does not find includes / libraries](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39126648/cmake-does-not-find-includes-libraries)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try to use `-DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/home/myaccount/otherlibs`? This will change `cmake`'s rules for searching configuration files and may help you here.

Comment: thanks a lot ,it works!  I thought `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` only tells makefile where to install the lib.

Comment: it has no `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` ,but has a `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX`, I changed the `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX`