# CMake - Qt: linking to wrong versions

Tags: c++, qt, cmake

I'm trying to compile a CMake project which requires Qt 5.6.1. The system has the Qt libraries and headers installed for Qt 5.5.1, so I manually compiled the 5.6.1 library. 
Then, Compiling the CMake project works fine, however the linker seems to link against 5.5.1 libraries as one of the linker errors seems to show:

```
[...]
qicucodec.cpp:(.text+0x1ede): undefined reference to `ucnv_countAvailable_55'
[...]
```

The CMakeLists.txt entry for Qt is

```
set(QT_VERSION_REQ "5.6.1")
find_package(Qt5Core ${QT_VERSION_REQ} REQUIRED)
find_package(Qt5Xml ${QT_VERSION_REQ} REQUIRED)
find_package(Qt5Network ${QT_VERSION_REQ} REQUIRED)
```

and those variables point to the manually compiled Qt version:

```
Qt5Core_DIR   /opt/build/qt/lib/cmake/Qt5Core
```

Any hints how to solve that issue?

Comment: Use CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH and add the location of the desired Qt library, cf. http://stackoverflow.com/q/39126648/2799037

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`QT5Core` depends on `libICU`, so you need to install it:

```
sudo apt-get install libicu55
```