# Setting QTDIR based on generator in use

Tags: qt, cmake

I am trying to setup a CMake project which consists of multiple static libraries and one main executable which has dependencies on QT. I would like to be able to select either a MinGW or a MSVC build when I run the cmake build.

I recently learned that the QT specific parts of CMake will find the installed library binaries for QT automatically if `QTDIR` is set as an environment variable and if `QTDIR/bin` is in the PATH.

Now I am wondering how I can set this information dynamically depending on the compiler that I am using. Since I would need to point cmake to either one of `C:\Qt\5.3\mingw482_32` or `C:\Qt\5.3\msvc2013_64`, or possibly others if I extend the list of targets in the future.

Note that I do not need to build both compiler targets at the same time, I would usually select on target in my IDE and build that one, but I would like to be able to switch between both targets.

The solution should be in such a way, that on Linux the CMake build will still find the libraries which are installed through the package manager automatically.

Can I easily achieve this with CMake?

As a side note, in the future I might also need to select the QT version on demand? So an extensible solution would be nice.

Comment: Just use `if(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID)` for check compiler, and set environment variable via `set(ENV{QTDIR} ...)`. Some `FindXXX.cmake` scripts use given logic. See e.g. [FindBoost.cmake](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/master/Modules/FindBoost.cmake).

Comment: When running CMake, I pass `-DCMAKE_MODULE_PATH=<dir>` - the directory where the `FindXXX.cmake` files of the Qt are. That effectively selects what installation of Qt to use.

Comment: Use CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH, cf. http://stackoverflow.com/a/39126731/2799037