# CMAKE - Finding Libraries

Tags: c++, cmake, cmake-gui

How do you get CMAKE to find libraries without editing the CMAKE script? I've got OpenSceneGraph 3.2 distribution and it cannot find ZLIB, JPEG, PNG, TIFF, several others. I have each API built on disk.

I have been unable to discern how to get CMAKE to find these libraries. Do I need to set environment variables for each? Command line options?

I found the cmake -E env EnvironmentVariableName="Hello World" approach but I can't find any documentation to tell me what to name any env variable ...

On linux cmake finds everything Ok, on Windows nope ...

In the past I would do the following:
mkdir release_build
cd release_build
cmake ../ -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=../ -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release
Then I would open the script with cmake-gui and manually set the includes and libs for the API's
I'd like to be able to do this without the 2nd step of manually editing the script with cmake-gui

Thanks!
P

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CMake does not find includes / libraries](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39126648/cmake-does-not-find-includes-libraries)

Comment: Bingo, been searching for days ... how could I have missed this
Thanks!
P