# Building a project with SFML library using CMake

Tags: cmake, sfml

Similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41624614/building-a-project-with-sfml-library-via-cmake?rq=1) I'm trying to build a project with SFML using CMake.

My CMakeLists.txt file is:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6)
project(pong)

# Specify C++11 flag for g++
if(CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCXX OR "${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID}" STREQUAL "Clang")
        set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11 -O2")
endif()

# Add directory containing FindSFML.cmake to module path
set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake/Modules/" ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH})

# Add sources
file(GLOB SOURCES
    "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/*.cpp"
)

# Find SFML
set(SFML_ROOT "C:/Users/usr/Downloads/_ Downloads (new)_/SFML-2.4.2-linux-gcc-64-bit/SFML-2.4.2")
find_package( SFML COMPONENTS audio graphics window system REQUIRED )

if(SFML_FOUND)
        include_directories(${SFML_INCLUDE_DIR})
    target_link_libraries(pong ${SFML_LIBRARIES})
else()
        #set(SFML_ROOT "" CACHE PATH "SFML top-level directory")
        message("\n-> SFML directory not found. Set SFML_ROOT to SFML's top-level path (containing \"include\" and \"lib\" 

directories).")
        message("-> Make sure the SFML libraries with the same configuration (Release/Debug, Static/Dynamic) exist.\n")
endif()

add_executable(pong ${SOURCES})
```

When I try to build it [using MinGW-w64 + MSYS2] on Windows, I get the following error:

```
CMake Error at cmake/Modules/FindSFML.cmake:307 (message):
  Could NOT find SFML (missing: SFML_AUDIO_LIBRARY SFML_GRAPHICS_LIBRARY
  SFML_WINDOW_LIBRARY SFML_SYSTEM_LIBRARY)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:19 (find_package)
```

I don't know why the libraries are not found.

Please help me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CMake does not find includes / libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39126648/cmake-does-not-find-includes-libraries)

Comment: Habe a look at https://stackoverflow.com/q/39126648/2799037 and if it doesn't help, report back with more details.

Comment: I commented out `set(SFML_ROOT "C:/Users/usr/Downloads/_ Downloads (new)_/SFML-2.4.2-linux-gcc-64-bit/SFML-2.4.2")`, then supplied cmake with the switch `-DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH="C:/Users/usr/Downloads/_ Downloads (new)_/SFML-2.4.2-linux-gcc-64-bit/SFML-2.4.2"`; then I re-ran CMake, deleting build files & directories previously built (such as CMakeCache.txt). .. Still, the same error.

Comment: According to directory `SFML-2.4.2-linux-gcc-64-bit` you have downloaded *Linux* version of SFML. But MinGW is NOT Linux. At [download page](https://www.sfml-dev.org/download/sfml/2.4.2/) you need to look into *Windows* section and choose file corresponded to gcc. [This page](https://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.4/start-cb.php) describes how to select proper SFML binaries for MinGW.

Comment: @Tsyvarev [This page](https://www.sfml-dev.org/download/sfml/2.4.2/) has various pre-built versions of SFML; it also says compiler versions must match exactly.. my MinGW version is 6.3, while the specific prebuilt libraries were built with v. 6.1. .. I'm assuming then that I have to build the entire library again using my version.

Comment: Yes, in that case you need to built the library by yourself.

Comment: - Side-question: Is there a way to use GCC 6.1 instead of 6.3 in my MinGW?

Comment: - Side-side-question: How do I check my version of GCC in MinGW?