# cmake not finding a configuration file for pdal

Tags: cmake

I am trying to configure the [Point Data Abstraction Library](https://www.pdal.io/index.html) in Windows using CMake. I am following a tutorial that can be found [here](https://www.pdal.io/development/cmake.html):

I am using the following command in the command prompt:

```
C:\Users\name\PDALe\build> cmake .. -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=C:\OSGeo4W64\lib\pdal\cmake
```

However, the following warning appears:

> CMake Warning at CMakeLists.txt:3 (find_package):
>     Could not find a configuration file for package "PDAL" that is compatible
>     with requested version "1.6.0".
>     The following configuration files were considered but not accepted:
>     C:/OSGeo4W64/lib/pdal/cmake/PDALConfig.cmake, version: 1.6.0 (64bit)

This is exactly the configuration file I want it to use, I'm not sure why it isn't using it. I have seen a similar [idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39126648/cmake-does-not-find-includes-libraries), but I think I have directed cmake to the config file correctly.

Is there something simple I'm missing? Does anyone know what is going wrong here?

**Edit**: My current CMakeLists.txt is as follows:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
project(MY_PDAL_PROJECT)
find_package(PDAL REQUIRED CONFIG)
include_directories(${PDAL_INCLUDE_DIRS})
link_directories(${PDAL_LIBRARY_DIRS})
add_definitions(${PDAL_DEFINITIONS})
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-std=c++11")
add_executable(tutorial Tutorial.cpp)
target_link_libraries(tutorial PRIVATE ${PDAL_LIBRARIES})
```

I have only changed the line `find_package(PDAL REQUIRED CONFIG)` from `find_package(PDAL 1.6.0 REQUIRED CONFIG)` since I asked the question.

Comment: It seems that existing configuration has version `1.6.0 (64bit)`. You probably need to specify exactly that version in `find_package()` call: `find_package(PDAL "1.6.0 (64bit)" REQUIRED CONFIG)`.

Comment: Thank you, I have now tried that. The problem is that it doesn't seem to like that as an argument: `CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:3 (find_package):
  find_package called with invalid argument "1.6.0 (64bit)"`. I also tried `find_package(PDAL 1.6.0 (64bit) REQUIRED CONFIG)` and got: `CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:3 (find_package):
  find_package called with invalid argument "("`

Comment: Hmm, actually I first time see version string with `()` in it and not sure whether CMake processes it correctly. However, if you have only one `PDAL` package, you may just omit version argument in `find_package()` call.

Comment: That doesn't seem to do it either unfortunately: `CMake Warning at CMakeLists.txt:3 (find_package):
  Could not find a configuration file for package "PDAL" that is compatible
  with requested version "".

  The following configuration files were considered but not accepted:

    C:/OSGeo4W64/lib/pdal/cmake/PDALConfig.cmake, version: 1.6.0 (64bit)`

Comment: Hm, "omiting version argument" means `find_package(PDAL REQUIRED CONFIG)`. In that case CMake shouldn't compare versions.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I changed it to when it gave that error. I'll edit my original post to give my CMakeLists.txt file in it's entirety as it stands.

Comment: Looks like CMake simply doesn't support version string like `1.6.0 (64bit)`, and the project (PDAL) shouldn't use it.

Answer (score 3):

Basically, CMake is telling you that it has found a 64 Bit version of the PDAL library, but that does not match with the number of bits CMake has deduced you compiler is using.

Therefore, Cmake is adding the '(64bit)' to the version string.

Try to double check that your environment is in fact set up to a 64 bit compiler. You should be able to verify that from the  CMakeError.txt or CMakeOutput.txt files that are somewhere in your build directory.

Either the path to the compiler will give you a clue, or the first output line from the compiler itself. For example mine says:

Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing compiler version 19.14.26433 for **x64**