# CMake: OGREConfig.cmake

Tags: c++, gcc, cmake, ogre

I have this weird issue that very few people seem to be having with Ogre3D, where CMake is unable to find (er, "accept") OGREConfig.cmake. Here's my console output:

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:10 (find_package):
  Could not find a configuration file for package "OGRE" that is compatible
  with requested version "1.12.7".

  The following configuration files were considered but not accepted:

    D:/_lib/ogre/build/sdk/CMake/OGREConfig.cmake, version: 1.12.7 (64bit)
```

I have no idea if I'm just being a moron or what, but I made sure to set OGRE_DIR in the environment variables and I even built Ogre from source, following instructions to a T. Here's my CMakeLists.txt for the project:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.17.2)

set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER gcc)
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER g++)

project(OgreProject1 VERSION 0.0.1 LANGUAGES C CXX)


# specify which version and components you need
find_package(
  OGRE 1.12.7
  COMPONENTS
    Bites
    RTShaderSystem
  REQUIRED
)
# copy resource.cfg next to our binaries where OGRE looks for it
file(COPY ${OGRE_CONFIG_DIR}/resources.cfg DESTINATION ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR})
# add the source files as usual
add_executable(cmake-good src/main.cpp)
# this also sets the includes and pulls third party dependencies
target_link_libraries(cmake-good OgreBites OgreRTShaderSystem)
```

This seems like a "me" problem and not an "ogre" problem, so if you could set me in the right direction that would be great. I will edit my post with more information if prompted.

NOTE: If it's important, I built Ogre with MSVC16, and my CMake version is 3.17.2.

Comment: There is a response to a very similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51620714/3987854) that may help. It looks like your Ogre is built for 64-bit, but in your CMake project are you also using a 64-bit compiler?

Comment: How do I check for the amount of bits specified by the compiler?

Comment: With which [generator](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-generators.7.html) do you build your project? It seems not MSVC, as you use gcc compiler.