# CMake and fftw3.h in OS X

Tags: c++, macos, cmake, fftw

I am trying to build pfstools, an HDR processing package, in a Mac running OS X 10.9.5. I have installed fftw, as well as other dependencies, using macports, which installed 'fftw3.h' in 'opt/local/include'.

I have included the following line in the file 'CMakelists.txt'.

> include_directories(“/opt/local/include”)

After running 'CMake' successfully, I run 'make' and get the following error.

> /Users/gustavomata/Desktop/pfstools-2.1.0/src/tmo/durand02>/fastbilateral.cpp:34:10: fatal error:
>
> 'fftw3.h' file not found

Any hints?

Gustavo J. Mata

Comment: Is it a wrong copy, or quotes around the include directory are *non-standard* (`”`)?

Comment: Learn how to include a third-party library, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/39126648/2799037. If your problem persists, ask with a minimal, reproducable example.