# I use cmake to compile vorbis file. It is pop up an error when configure file

Tags: cmake

Selecting Windows SDK version 10.0.18362.0 to target Windows 10.0.19041.
Configuring vorbis 1.3.7

CMake Error at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.19/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:218 (message):
Could NOT find Ogg (missing: OGG_LIBRARY OGG_INCLUDE_DIR)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.19/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:577 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
cmake/FindOgg.cmake:73 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
CMakeLists.txt:65 (find_package)

Comment: The Ogg dependency (library and headers/includes) are not found. You have to provide/install them, clear the cmake cache, and re-run cmake.

Comment: Not an exact duplicate, but handles your question in a general way: https://stackoverflow.com/q/39126648/2799037